# Cache clear/clear data of the app

Tags: javascript, cordova

As i am new to phone gap,whenever the user clicks on the clear data/cache clear by going to in mobile settings-->Application Manager-->when clicks on app then he will see there all the things about clearing ...,but when ever he clicks on that button how to show the end-user an alert by mentioning all the data will be erased and at the same time we show collect that data and we should store in the database

Comment: What are you asking?  I am not sure to be honest

Comment: when ever the end-user clears the app cache/clear data in the mobile, show him alert 'do you clear the data',if yes then collect the data and store in the server db..

Comment: Do any other app's do that, like the Facebook app? I dont think so

Comment: Its not possible. Unless u make changes in android os

Comment: when he click  on clear/cache data collect all the data from there immediately store in the server db..but i haven't seen that.but this is the requirement,but how to that implement alternative show me.